# Limit/restrict width re-size FXML window

Tags: window, javafx-8

I am having one FXML window and it is resizing by default. I want to put some width lets say 350, when I am resizing it, it should not allow me to shrink after width reaches 350.

I have already tried with minWidth property but no luck so far.

Answer (score 2):

This is working just fine (minimum width 200 and maximum width 400):

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            primaryStage.setMinWidth(200);
            primaryStage.setMaxWidth(400);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Have a look at [`Stage#setMinWidth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setMinWidth-double-).